# Barycentric coordinates

Tags: euclidean-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Can anybody here explain to me, starting from scratch, how it is that barycentric coordinates work? In case you don't have the time to do so, what's in your opinion the book (or books) that anybody willing to acquire a working command of barycentric coordinates ought to study?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) explains it quite well.

Comment: I recommend you www.mit.edu/~evanchen/handouts/bary/bary-full.pdf